# Is my novel too short?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, novel, fantasy

This is my first time trying to write a book, and I usually just plow through stories so fast that it ends up being like 50 pages. I'm at 73 pages right now, wordcount being a bit over 10,000. It's probably going to be around 150 pages total, as I find too many subplots boring. Is this too short?

Comment: "Not even a teenager"? I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but you have to be 13 or over to use this site, as per the Terms and Conditions.

Comment: I know but I turn thirteen in a couple days soooo I decided it would be fine xd

Comment: Well, while I'm obliged to report underage accounts to the community managers for deletion, it's possible they may not have handled your case by then. If your account does get deleted, though, you can just create a new account after your 13th birthday, and I *believe* it's possible for you to get in touch with the community managers yourself and ask that they merge your old posts with your new account.

Comment: @FiercestarTheCat You don't just get to "decide".

Comment: I live in the U.S., not the EU. I know that 13 is the usual thing in the U.S.

Comment: While Nai45 is correct that writing critiques are off-topic within questions, we *do* have a (semi-active) [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115415/beta-reviewers-reviewing) for requesting or providing critiques. You could try posting the link to your draft there instead.

Comment: Check this (and other similar sources on the net out): https://www.helpingwritersbecomeauthors.com/5-fun-and-easy-ways-to-lengthen-word/ However, maybe it's a short story? The lack of subplots might suggest it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too short is relative. For a novel, probably. For a novella, perhaps. For a short story, no. For flash fiction, too long.

Don't worry about length. Worry about whether you have told the story in the number of words needed. I started writing a short story; it turned into four (short) novels. The story just kept developing. However, I wanted to write another novel and the idea I had was only a short story.

Write and revise. That way you become a good writer.

I wrote several stories at your age I thought were good. However, they weren't novel length. Writing, not length, is what is important.

Comment: Thank you. I'm planning on turning it into a trilogy, but I may have to combine all three into one, maybe separating it into parts. I remember reading a series where they called each part like Book 1 Book 2 Book 3.